# Multiprocessing sends value of the object instead of the object as an argument when passed alone

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

**main_script.py**

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes
from os import getpid

from slave_script import monitor

communication_line = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_char, b"0")
m = multiprocessing.Process(target=monitor, args=(communication_line))
m.start()
m.join()
```

**slave_script.py**

```
from time import sleep

def monitor(communication_line):

    while 1:
        print(type(communication_line))
        sleep(2)
```

running **main_script.py** keeps returning *<class 'bytes'>* with a value of *b"0"*.

BUT, when passing another dummy data as an argument, the slave receives it as an object.

So, modifying **main_script.py** 's #8 line to:

```
m = multiprocessing.Process(target=monitor, args=(communication_line, 6969))
```

And modifying **slave_script.py** 's #3 line to:

```
def monitor(communication_line, dummy_data_to_ignore):
```

keeps returning (what I am trying to achieve) *<class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.SynchronizedString'>*

So, I am confused, why didn't it see the *communication_line* as an object until I sent another data alongside with it?

Comment: You're missing a comma from `args` in your first example, you are passing the array as args not a tuple with the array as the only arg: `args=(communication_line, )`

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh indeed it worked with the comma alone. But can you clarify why the comm is needed? Isn't it also sent as tuple without the comma?

Comment: A comma is what denotes a tuple not parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` parameter must be a tuple.  `(communication_line)` is not a tuple.  A comma makes a tuple.  Parentheses are only needed for order of operations.  Consider `1`, `(1)`, `((1))` are all integer one. But `1,`, `(1,)` and `((1,))` are all tuples.  Use `args = (communication_line,)`.

Or another example:

```py
>>> x=1,
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> x=(1)
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
```